# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsmutabledictionary

I am beginning with iOS development, I have this code :

First of all I declare the listOfItems NSMutableArray:

```
@interface SAMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
}
@end
```

And now, here is the part the code that gives me an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5fc260000)" error.
The error is given in the last line of the "individual_data" object.

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *tweetDict in statuses) {
    NSString  *text          = [tweetDict objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString  *screenName    = [[tweetDict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
    NSString  *img_url       = [[tweetDict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
    NSInteger unique_id      = [[tweetDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
    NSInteger user_id        = [[[tweetDict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"] intValue ];

    NSMutableDictionary *individual_data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            text, @"text_tweet",
                                            screenName,@"user_name",
                                            img_url, @"img_url",
                                            unique_id, @"unique_id",
                                            user_id, @"user_id", nil];
    [listOfItems addObject:individual_data];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you call initWithCapacity:20 on your dictionary?

Comment: Actually it should be initialized with the capacity of the number statuses.

Comment: Yeah I just through 20 in there as an example.  You are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not put `NSInteger`s or any other non Objective-C class inside of an array or dictionary. You need to wrap them in an [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSMutableDictionary *individual_data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            text, @"text_tweet",
                                            screenName,@"user_name",
                                            img_url, @"img_url",
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:unique_id], @"unique_id",
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:user_id], @"user_id", nil];
//Or if you want to use literals
NSMutableDictionary *individual_data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            text, @"text_tweet",
                                            screenName,@"user_name",
                                            img_url, @"img_url",
                                            @(unique_id), @"unique_id",
                                            @(user_id), @"user_id", nil];
```

Comment: Thats what where here for. Also if `[tweetDict objectForKey:@"id"]` returns an `NSNumber*` then you should just store them as an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Got it, thank you, I am really excited to learn this language.